# Remove '-' and capitalize the string before

Tags: php

I'm trying to remove the '-' from a string and capitalize the word before the '-'. For example:

**fraser-ultra-2019** becomes **FraserUltra2019**

Right now I can only remove the '-' with str_replace but not sure how to capitalize it.

```
$string = fraser-ultra-2019
str_replace("-","",$string) // fraserultra2019
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $string)));
```

The `ucwords()` function will capitalise all words in a given string so long as they are split by a space.

Be sure to wrap your `$string` value in single or double quotes before writing this to a PHP file.